# Setting up multi datacenter cluster using OpsCenter

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax, opscenter

Can we create a multi datacenter cluster using OpsCenter alone?  I am able to create one ring, but it is not clear how I can specify the data center settings for the nodes in the second ring.

Comment: I believe OpsCenter will create different DC's based on the workload type (c*, solr, analytics)

Comment: I did not follow that.  I have only C* nodes, and I want to setup two rings, one in each DC. How do I go about creating such a cluster in OpsCenter?

Answer (score 3):

Currently it's not possible to create a multi datacenter cluster with OpsCenter. It can **manage** such a cluster if you create it yourself, but cannot **create** one.

Here are the relevant docs for doing a multi-DC install:

- Cassandra: [Initializing a multiple node cluster (multiple data centers)](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/initialize/initializeMultipleDS.html)
- DSE: [Multiple data center deployment per workload type](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/deploy/deployMultiDC.html)

FYI regarding @phact comment above: OpsCenter does automatically create separate logical datacenters when using DataStax Enterprise, separating the workload into Cassandra, Solr, and Analytics DCs. However it does not support creating multiple Cassandra-only datacenters, for example.